# Reset toggle in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I am trying to build a mobile slide out menu and want to add the `.on("swipeleft",...)` function for the slide effect on mobile. However the issue I am having is when the user slides the menu back it get's stuck and repeats the function becuase it looks back to the `mobileMenuSlideIn()`. Which means the user needs to click on the button twice. What I am trying to do is check if the function is called and if it is don't repeat it. How can I do this?

```
function mobileMenu(){
    /* Slide out function */
    function mobileMenuSlideOut(){
        jQuery('.mobile-wrapper').animate({ marginLeft: "70%" }, 'slow', function() {
            jQuery(".mobile-wrapper").css("position", "fixed"); 
        });
        jQuery('.mobile-wrapper-sidebar').animate({ marginLeft: "0px" }, 'slow');
    }   
    /* Slide int function */
    function mobileMenuSlideIn(){   
        jQuery('.mobile-wrapper').animate({ marginLeft: "0px" }, 'slow', function() {
            jQuery(".mobile-wrapper").css("position", "relative");
        });
        jQuery('.mobile-wrapper-sidebar').animate({ marginLeft: "-70%" }, 'slow');
    }   
    /* Toggle to create mobile menu */
    jQuery('[data-toggle="mobile-wrapper"]').toggle(     
            /* Add the swipe function for mobile */
            function() {    
                mobileMenuSlideOut();

                jQuery( ".mobile-wrapper" ).on("swipeleft", function() {    
                    mobileMenuSlideIn();    
                });
            },
            function() { 
                if ( !mobileMenuSlideIn()) {
                    mobileMenuSlideIn();
                }
                else {
                    //do nothing

                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: not sure exactly what you want, but a very basic way to stop a function running many times is to use flags. (running = "no"; if (running == "no") { running = "yes"; do the work here and at the end set a timeout function to set the flag to running = "no" after a few seconds }) give it go, most times it works. Set a global variable (var running;) outside the functions so it can be read in any function

Comment: Thank you @Tasos for your response. Basically what I want to do is when the user click on the menu icon ([data-toggle="mobile-wrapper"]) the menu will slide out from the left and when the user clicks on the menu icon the menu will slide back in. This works fine with a toggle but when I add this to the first toggle which slides the menu out: 

.mobile-wrapper" ).on("swipeleft",function(){ 

the function mobileMenuSlideIn runs twice which means the user needs to click on the icon twice to slide the menu out again. I need the function mobileMenuSlideIn() to only run if it hasn't been run before.

Comment: i see. it may be difficult to reset a toggles state. You may have to use click function instead and use the flag method i mentioned above. so you would know if its open  or closed. i found this but im not sure if it will help -- http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-check-toggle-open/